# Short story published in a magazine: 100 humans are brought to aliens to explain why humans didn't save Earth when it was about to be destroyed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

100 humans, including a winner of a beauty pageant, are brought up to aliens who want to learn more about humanity, and ultimately why humans didn’t save planet Earth when they knew century earlier it was being destroyed and beyond the point of no return.

Comment: Hey there. That's some good info already! Though, could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, how long ago is "years ago", 50s, 80s, three years ago? As well as any other plot point/details you could remember; everyuthing helps! Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like the short story "The Janitor On Mars" by Martin Amis, published in The New Yorker on October 26, 1998. [Link to the abstract is here](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1998/10/26/the-janitor-on-mars).

From [an essay about the story](http://www.omphalosbookreviews.com/index.php/reviews/info/299):

> The Janitor on Mars is about the sole surviving Martian. Mankind has
> crossed some threshold called "the tripwire," and as a result the
> Janitor took over CNN to broadcast his presence, and invite a coterie
> of the intelligent and the beautiful (excluding only politicians and
> clergy) to come to Mars and learn the Janitor's secrets. So a mission
> was cobbled together, with some help from the Janitor, and eighty-five
> or so people went to Mars to hear him out. When they arrived on Mars,
> inside Olympus Mons to be precise, the first thing that they learned
> was that the Janitor was a robot, and that all the Martians were gone.
> The robot told the tale of the history of the Martians, who matured as
> a race very quickly after the planets of Mars and Earth were formed,
> built up a glorious culture, then, mostly out of boredom, blasted
> themselves almost out of existence. The Martians, in keeping with
> legends that would be written about their patron billions of years in
> the future and an entire planet away, were a very warlike race. They
> were also highly advanced. In an uncountable series of wars they
> destroyed themselves in seconds, then built their culture back up over
> hundreds of thousands of years only to do it again and again and
> again.

The New Yorker link has a link to the story in its archives, but you need to be a subscriber to read it.